# Excel VBA function terminates after first loop of for/next loop without finishing function

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I just wrote this code to perform an iterative calculation. It finds the X,Y coordinates where an unknown parabola is tangent to a known circle. It is based on other iterative functions I've written that have worked flawlessly. I'm stumped as to what the issue is. Here is the code:

```
Public Function Jext(PA As Double, Xcl As Double, Ycl As Double, Ctr As Double, Rnl As Double, Finl As Double) As Double
Pi = 3.14159265358979
tol = 0.00000001
Dim x(20) As Double
Dim Yc(20) As Double
Dim Yp(20) As Double
Dim A(20) As Double
Dim Diff(20) As Double
Dim It As Integer
Dim hF As Double
Dim Sf As Double
'Xcl is the horizontal position of the root radius center line
'Ycl is the vertical position of the root radius center line
'Ctr is root radius. It's an approximation of the trochoid and is typically the cutter tip radius
'Rnl is the radius to the point where the load line intersects the tooth centerline. It is the apex of the parabola
'x is the horizontal position that is common to the parabola and circle. It is the independent variable
'Yc is the vertical position on the circle at point x
'Yp is the vertical position on the parabola at point x
'A is the leading term of the parabolic equation
'Diff is the calculated difference in vertical positions of circle and parabola
'Set initial guess values. x(0) is 5% of the radius (left edge of circle) and x(1) is 95% of the radius(bottom of the circle)
x(0) = (Xcl - Ctr) + 0.05 * Ctr
x(1) = (Xcl - Ctr) + 0.95 * Ctr
Yc(0) = Ycl - (Ctr ^ 2 - (x(0) - Xcl) ^ 2) ^ 0.5
Yc(1) = Ycl - (Ctr ^ 2 - (x(1) - Xcl) ^ 2) ^ 0.5
A(0) = Tan(WorksheetFunction.Acos((Xcl - x(0)) / Ctr) + Pi / 2) / (2 * x(0))
A(1) = Tan(WorksheetFunction.Acos((Xcl - x(1)) / Ctr) + Pi / 2) / (2 * x(1))
Yp(0) = A(0) * x(0) ^ 2 + Rnl
Yp(1) = A(1) * x(1) ^ 2 + Rnl
Diff(0) = Yp(0) - Yc(0)
Diff(1) = Yp(1) - Yc(1)
For It = 1 To 19 Step 1
    x(It + 1) = x(It) - (Diff(It) - 0) * (x(It - 1) - x(It)) / (Diff(It - 1) - Diff(It))
    Yc(It + 1) = Ycl - (Ctr ^ 2 - (x(It + 1) - Xcl) ^ 2) ^ 0.5
    A(It + 1) = Tan(WorksheetFunction.Acos((Xcl - x(It + 1)) / Ctr) + Pi / 2) / (2 * x(It + 1))
    Yp(It + 1) = A(It + 1) * x(It + 1) ^ 2 + Rnl
    Diff(It + 1) = Yp(It + 1) - Yc(It + 1)
    If Abs(Diff(It + 1)) < tol Then Exit For
Debug.Print Diff(It + 1)
Next It
hF = Rnl - Yp(t + 1)
Sf = 2 * x(t + 1)
Jext = 1 / (Cos(Finl) / Cos(PA) * (6 * hF / Sf ^ 2 - Tan(Finl) / Sf))
End Function
```

I put a stop at the "Next It" line to check the values as it went through the iterative loops. When I execute the code, all of the values are as expected and the value of Abs(Diff(It+1)) is not small enough to exit the for loop in the IF statement. I put the Debug.Print statement in there to make sure it was getting that far in the code and it did print Diff(It+1). So it executes everything to that point. Then when I continue the function it just stops and returns a #VALUE error in the spreadsheet. I've no idea why it won't continue the for loop. Anyone see something I've missed?

Comment: It's usually better to debug by calling this from another subroutine (step through with F8 too), instead of trying to debug by calling it as a UDF in a cell.

Comment: I'm going to assume this may have something to do with it? `If Abs(Diff(It + 1)) < tol Then Exit For` - put a breakpoint on that line and check the values.